# PostgreSQL - Very slow to connect to fresh database

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, database-connection

I just installed Postgres (v12.2) and created a database, but it's taking around ~20 seconds to connect (using psql). This seems to be a long time and it's causing problems in some of my workflows.

I installed PostgreSQL using Anaconda (for corporate reasons I don't have access to either apt or Docker). Here are the steps I followed to get the database up and running:

```
conda install postgresql
initdb -D airflow
pg_ctl -D airflow -l logfile start
createuser --encrypted --pwprompt airflow_user
createdb --owner=airflow_user airflow_db
```

I also changed the following lines on the pg_hba.conf file:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
```

and set the logs to be as verbose as possible on the postgresql.conf file (also added a couple of things like the application name to the log message).

Testing the connection with:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d airflow_db -U airflow_user
```

yields the following log messages:

```
2021-02-17 15:56:25.590 UTC [unknown] [unknown] LOG:  connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=45006
2021-02-17 15:56:41.454 UTC   DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2021-02-17 15:56:41.454 UTC   DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2021-02-17 15:56:41.455 UTC   DEBUG:  received inquiry for database 0
2021-02-17 15:56:41.455 UTC   DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2021-02-17 15:56:41.455 UTC   DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.stat"
2021-02-17 15:56:41.466 UTC   DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2021-02-17 15:56:41.466 UTC   DEBUG:  my backend ID is 3
2021-02-17 15:56:41.466 UTC   DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2021-02-17 15:56:41.467 UTC   DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2021-02-17 15:56:41.467 UTC   DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "airflow_db"
2021-02-17 15:56:41.467 UTC   DEBUG:  received inquiry for database 16385
2021-02-17 15:56:41.467 UTC   DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2021-02-17 15:56:41.467 UTC   DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat_tmp/db_16385.stat"
2021-02-17 15:56:41.467 UTC   DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.stat"
2021-02-17 15:56:41.477 UTC   DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2021-02-17 15:56:41.477 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_statistic: vac: 0 (threshold 134), anl: 0 (threshold 92)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_type: vac: 0 (threshold 131), anl: 0 (threshold 91)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_authid: vac: 0 (threshold 52), anl: 1 (threshold 51)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_attribute: vac: 0 (threshold 633), anl: 0 (threshold 341)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_proc: vac: 0 (threshold 642), anl: 0 (threshold 346)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_class: vac: 0 (threshold 129), anl: 0 (threshold 90)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_index: vac: 0 (threshold 82), anl: 0 (threshold 66)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_operator: vac: 0 (threshold 204), anl: 0 (threshold 127)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_opclass: vac: 0 (threshold 76), anl: 0 (threshold 63)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_am: vac: 0 (threshold 51), anl: 0 (threshold 51)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_amop: vac: 0 (threshold 193), anl: 0 (threshold 122)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_amproc: vac: 0 (threshold 139), anl: 0 (threshold 95)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_rewrite: vac: 0 (threshold 75), anl: 0 (threshold 63)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_cast: vac: 0 (threshold 93), anl: 0 (threshold 72)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_namespace: vac: 0 (threshold 51), anl: 0 (threshold 51)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_database: vac: 0 (threshold 50), anl: 1 (threshold 50)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_tablespace: vac: 0 (threshold 50), anl: 0 (threshold 50)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_shdepend: vac: 0 (threshold 52), anl: 1 (threshold 51)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  pg_toast_2618: vac: 0 (threshold 100), anl: 0 (threshold 75)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 7 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  exit(0)
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
2021-02-17 15:56:41.478 UTC   DEBUG:  server process (PID 29567) exited with exit code 0
2021-02-17 15:56:47.646 UTC [unknown] [unknown] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:47.646 UTC [unknown] [unknown] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:47.646 UTC [unknown] [unknown] DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 1 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:47.646 UTC [unknown] [unknown] DEBUG:  exit(0)
2021-02-17 15:56:47.646 UTC [unknown] [unknown] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:47.646 UTC [unknown] [unknown] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:47.646 UTC [unknown] [unknown] DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:47.647 UTC   DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=29613 socket=9
2021-02-17 15:56:47.647 UTC   DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
2021-02-17 15:56:47.647 UTC   DEBUG:  server process (PID 29413) exited with exit code 0
2021-02-17 15:56:47.647 UTC [unknown] [unknown] LOG:  connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=45008
2021-02-17 15:56:47.647 UTC [unknown] airflow_user DEBUG:  postgres child[29613]: starting with (
2021-02-17 15:56:47.647 UTC [unknown] airflow_user DEBUG:   postgres
2021-02-17 15:56:47.647 UTC [unknown] airflow_user DEBUG:  )
2021-02-17 15:56:47.647 UTC [unknown] airflow_user DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2021-02-17 15:56:47.648 UTC [unknown] airflow_user DEBUG:  my backend ID is 3
2021-02-17 15:56:47.648 UTC [unknown] airflow_user DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2021-02-17 15:56:47.648 UTC [unknown] airflow_user LOG:  connection authorized: user=airflow_user database=airflow_db application_name=psql
2021-02-17 15:56:47.649 UTC psql airflow_user DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2021-02-17 15:56:50.746 UTC psql airflow_user DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:50.746 UTC psql airflow_user DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 6 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:50.746 UTC psql airflow_user DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 4 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:50.746 UTC psql airflow_user LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:03.098 user=airflow_user database=airflow_db host=127.0.0.1 port=45008
2021-02-17 15:56:50.746 UTC psql airflow_user DEBUG:  exit(0)
2021-02-17 15:56:50.746 UTC psql airflow_user DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:50.746 UTC psql airflow_user DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:50.746 UTC psql airflow_user DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:56:50.746 UTC   DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
2021-02-17 15:56:50.746 UTC   DEBUG:  server process (PID 29613) exited with exit code 0
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  postmaster received signal 2
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  sending signal 15 to process 26962
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  logical replication launcher shutting down
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 5 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 2 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 6 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  exit(0)
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 6 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(1): 2 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  exit(0)
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  exit(1)
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 5 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  exit(0)
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.668 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.669 UTC   DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
2021-02-17 15:57:00.669 UTC   LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 26962) exited with exit code 1
2021-02-17 15:57:00.669 UTC   DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
2021-02-17 15:57:00.669 UTC   LOG:  shutting down
2021-02-17 15:57:00.670 UTC   DEBUG:  performing replication slot checkpoint
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  attempting to remove WAL segments older than log file 000000000000000000000000
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  SlruScanDirectory invoking callback on pg_subtrans/0000
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 5 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  exit(0)
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat/global.stat"
2021-02-17 15:57:00.672 UTC   DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat/db_16385.stat"
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  removing temporary stats file "pg_stat_tmp/db_16385.stat"
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat/db_12738.stat"
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  removing temporary stats file "pg_stat_tmp/db_12738.stat"
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  writing stats file "pg_stat/db_0.stat"
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  removing temporary stats file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.stat"
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 5 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.673 UTC   DEBUG:  cleaning up dynamic shared memory control segment with ID 521889379
2021-02-17 15:57:00.676 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.676 UTC   LOG:  database system is shut down
2021-02-17 15:57:00.676 UTC   DEBUG:  exit(0)
2021-02-17 15:57:00.676 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.676 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.676 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.677 UTC   DEBUG:  logger shutting down
2021-02-17 15:57:00.677 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.677 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.677 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 0 callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.677 UTC   DEBUG:  exit(0)
2021-02-17 15:57:00.677 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.677 UTC   DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2021-02-17 15:57:00.677 UTC   DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
```

One thing I noticed is that between the "connection received" message and the very next step, it takes ~11 seconds. I've tested this on my personal desktop (not work) and the connection is almost instant, which seems to indicate that this is some sort of environment problem.

If anyone has any insight I would love to hear it! I've been blocked on this for ages now.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have got too many things mixed in the log, and there is not process number (`%p`).

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. There is something wrong with Anaconda's PostgreSQL package that was causing every connection attempt to fail once, and then succeed on the second try. No idea what exactly was going on, but we built PostgreSQL from source using good old make, and it works like a charm.

Cheers everyone